# Compile Error Using SWIG %native Function

Tags: java-native-interface, swig

I'm attempting to compile a native JNI call using the SWIG %native function and I'm getting the below exception for the header file. I'm including both the jdk-1.6.0_30/include and jdk-1.6.0_30/include/linux in the makefile below, Any ideas? I'm compiling on 32bit linux.

**Sample.h:**

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_jni_GetData (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

**SWIG.i:**

```
%module Sample
%{
   #include "Sample.h"
%}
%include "Sample.h"
%typemap(jstype) DeviceId getID "com.test.jni.DeviceId"
%typemap(jtype) DeviceId getID "com.test.jni.DeviceId"
%typemap(javaout) DeviceId getID { return $jnicall; }
%native(getID) DeviceId getID();
```

**Exception:**

```
[exec]Sample.h: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
[exec] make-3.79.1-p7: *** [sample_wrap.c] Error 1
```

**Makefile (not complete file):**

```
     PACKAGE_DIR = src/java/com/test/jni
     PACKAGE = com.test.jni
     INCLUDES = -I/user/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include/linux \
                -I/user/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include \
                -I/user/src/include #Sample.h resides here
     CFLAGS = -Wall -fpic $(INCLUDES) -O0 -g3
     SFLAGS = -java $(INCLUDES) -package $(PACKAGE) -outdir $(PACKAGE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got this in the wrong order. You need to **first** write:

```
%{
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_jni_GetData(JNIEnv *, jclass);
%}
```

so that when you write:

```
%native (GetData) jobject GetData();
```

a declaration of the function already exists in the wrapper code that SWIG will generate.

---

You can't `%include` Sample.h directly like that if it's got native functions in it. The SWIG preprocessor doesn't know what JNIEXPORT or JNICALL are - they look like syntax errors unless they've been given as a macro.

I'd suggest putting the native functions in a separate header file which you then *only* `#include`, not `%include` that file.

Failing that you have several options open though, hiding the native function from SWIG, e.g.:

```
#ifndef SWIG
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_jni_GetData (JNIEnv *, jclass);
#endif
```

in the header file would work, or you could modify the interface file to make SWIG ignore JNIEXPORT and JNICALL:

```
%module Sample
%{
   #include "Sample.h"
%}
#define JNIEXPORT
#define JNICALL
%include "Sample.h"
%typemap(jstype) DeviceId getID "com.test.jni.DeviceId"
%typemap(jtype) DeviceId getID "com.test.jni.DeviceId"
%typemap(javaout) DeviceId getID { return $jnicall; }
%native(getID) DeviceId getID();
```

Although in that case SWIG will try to wrap it as well as take the `%native` directive which probably isn't what you want!

Comment: I had a typo in my initial question, corrected now.  The %native line is the last line in my swig.i and the JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_jni_GetData (JNIEnv *, jclass); is in the Sample.h file which gets included before the %native call.  I think maybe there is an additional qualifier of some type that needs to go in the Sample.h file for the function, but just thinking out loud.

Comment: thanks for the various solutions, great answer.  I went back and looked at the SWIG documentation to see what the difference was between %include vs #include and what I get is SWIG processes %include functions but ignores #include functions. I basically have the same setup as I described in my original question.  What's the point of telling SWIG to ignore Sample.h (#include "Sample.h") but then include it with using %include "Sample.h"

Comment: When SWIG processes the %include it does actually do "normal" C pre-processing, which means if you want to %include all but part of a header file you can make it get ignored.

Comment: %include includes things as SWIG itself is running over the module file. Things within `%{ %}` like the #include get passed straight through to the _wrap.c file that SWIG generates